# What's wrong in this interface use?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

Suppose to have an interface like this:

```
interface MyInterface 
{
    public string AProperty { get; set;}

    public void AMethod ()
}
```

This interface is used inside another interface:

```
interface AnotherInterface
{
    public MyInterface member1 { get; set; }

    public int YetAnotherProperty {get; set;}
}
```

Now suppose to have two classes, one that implements each of the interfaces.

```
class MyInterfaceImpl : MyInterface
{
    private string aproperty
    public string AProperty
    {
        //... get and set inside
    }

    public void AMethod ()
    {
       //... do something
    }
}
```

And at last:

```
class AnotherInterfaceImpl : AnotherInterface
{
    private MyInterfaceImpl _member1;
    public MyIntefaceImpl member1
    {
        //... get and set inside
    }

    ...Other implementation
}
```

Why does the compiler complain that `AnotherInterfaceImpl` does not implement `MyInterface`?

I understand it is a very basic question... but I need to serialize to xml AnotherInterfaceImpl and I cannot do that if member1 is of type MyInterface.

Comment: If you can change `public MyIntefaceImpl member1` to `public MyInterface member1`, the compiler should be satisfied.

Comment: @Corak: This should be an answer.

Comment: The code and the error message don't match. The compiler should complain that `AnotherInterfaceImpl` does not implement `AnotherInterface`.

Comment: The code is so messed up and uncompilable it's really hard to tell what's really going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class `AnotherInterfaceImpl` is not actually implementing all members of `AnotherInterface`. The public property `AnotherInterfaceImpl.member1` must have type `MyInterface`, not `MyInterfaceImpl`.

Note that this restriction only applies to the public property. The private field `AnotherInterfaceImpl._member1` can still be of type `MyInterfaceImpl`, because `MyInterfaceImpl` implements `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the compiler complains that AnotherInterfaceImpl does not implement MyInterface?

Because it doesn't implement it. It has a member that implements it.

That is like saying "my customer object has an orders (list) property; how come my customer isn't a list?"

If you had either:

```
interface AnotherInterface : MyInterface
```

or

```
class AnotherInterfaceImpl : AnotherInterface, MyInterface
```

then it would be true to say that `AnotherInterfaceImpl` implemented `MyInterface`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to "explicitly" type your members as the interface defines them.

```
class AnotherInterfaceImpl : AnotherInterface
{
    private MyInterfaceImpl _member1;
    public MyInteface member1
    {
        get{ return _member1;}
        set{ _member1 = value;}
    }

    ...Other implementation
}
```